# PlutoSDR AttributeError: module 'iio' on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnu, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, iio, rtl-sdr

When attempting to run flow graph in GNU Radio Companion, I get the following error:
`AttributeError: module 'iio' has no attribute 'pluto_source'`

I am running a new VMWare environment, on Windows, for Ubuntu 20.04.

I first installed the drivers and the libiio library for the Pluto and was able to SSH via: `ssh root@192.168.21`
However, in terminal when I run `iio_info -s` I get the following output which concerns me.

```
Library version: 0.21 (git tag: 9d79757)
Compiled with backends: local xml ip usb
Unable to create Local IIO context : No such file or directory (2)
Available contexts:
    0: 0456:b673 (Analog Devices Inc. PlutoSDR (ADALM-PLUTO)), serial=1044739659930006f4ff24003edc27135f [usb:1.10.5]
    1: 192.168.2.1 (Analog Devices PlutoSDR Rev.B (Z7010-AD9364)), serial=1044739659930006f4ff24003edc27135f [ip:pluto.local]
```

Running `iio_info -u ip:192.168.2.1` I get a few errors which might be related to the above.

```
Library version: 0.21 (git tag: 9d79757)
Compiled with backends: local xml ip usb
IIO context created with network backend.
Backend version: 0.21 (git tag: v0.21  )
Backend description string: 192.168.2.1 Linux (none) 4.19.0-119999-g6edc6cd #319 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jul 6 15:45:01 CEST 2020 armv7l
IIO context has 9 attributes:
    hw_model: Analog Devices PlutoSDR Rev.B (Z7010-AD9364)
    hw_model_variant: 0
    hw_serial: 1044739659930006f4ff24003edc27135f
    fw_version: v0.32
    ad9361-phy,xo_correction: 39999954
    ad9361-phy,model: ad9364
    local,kernel: 4.19.0-119999-g6edc6cd
    uri: ip:192.168.2.1
    ip,ip-addr: 192.168.2.1
...
...
                attr 10: multichip_sync ERROR: Permission denied (13)
                attr 11: rssi_gain_step_error value: lna_error: 0 0 0 0
mixer_error: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
...
...
                debug attr 180: adi,frequency-division-duplex-mode-enable value: 1
                debug attr 181: direct_reg_access value: 0x0
        No trigger on this device
    iio:device2: xadc
        10 channels found:
            voltage5: vccoddr (input)
...
...
        2 debug attributes found:
                debug attr  0: pseudorandom_err_check value: CH0 : PN9 : Out of Sync : PN Error
CH1 : PN9 : Out of Sync : PN Error
                debug attr  1: direct_reg_access value: 0x0
        No trigger on this device
```

I was unsure what the errors were, so I re-flashed the PlutoSDR with the latest Firmware and tried again. Still same errors.

Any ideas what this would be from?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with GNU Radio Companion 3.8 (GRC) and Adalm Pluto. The root cause is that GRC requires a "tailored" iio package, which is different from the one you install via "pip install pylibiio." I can suggest the following:

1. Uninstall the Python iio (if you did, so as to avoid masking)
2. Make sure you install the gr-iio according to the official [guide](https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-software/gnuradio).
3. In the guide there are directions about making a copy of gr-iio installation and exporting its location to PYTHONPATH. Alternately, you can see some details from [my experience](https://techfocusalexn.wordpress.com/2021/04/03/setting-up-adalm-pluto-on-ubuntu/).
4. If you need to use Adalm Pluto with Python, without GRC, I can recommend creating a virtual environment (venv) and installing Python iio there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look into this. I managed to get Pluto up and running in GRC in Linux and I use my Windows machine along with Intelij IDEA for any Python coding. Maybe your post will give me one machine to rule them all.